# This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities. .All()

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `List` property that I am setting like so:

```
testCard.LstSummaries =
    db.Summaries.Where(
        x =>
            (x.AID == aId || x.AInformation.RegNumber == aRegNumber) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Day) == DateTime.Today.Date &&
            x.deleted == false).ToList();
```

Then I have a conditional statement:

```
if (testCard.LstSummaries.Count > 0)
{
    if (
        testCard.LstSummaries.All(
            x =>
                (x.AID == aId || // ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE
                 x.AInformation.RegNumber == aRegNumber) &&
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Day) == DateTime.Today.Date && x.deleted == false))
    {
        // .... do something
    }
```

I get an error:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

I want to avoid to make multiple calls to the database.. furthermore `testCard.LstSummaries` already has the values I am looking for.. but if I do this:

```
if (testCard.LstSummaries.Count > 0)
{
    if (
        db.Summaries.All(
            x =>
                (x.AID == aId || // NO ERROR
                 x.AInformation.RegNumber == aRegNumber) &&
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Day) == DateTime.Today.Date && x.deleted == false))
    {
        // .... do something
    }
```

I feel like making this call to the database is pointless because I would be retrieving the same results that are already stored in `testCard.LstSummaries`, but I can't invoke `.All()` because it's not `LINQ to Entities`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: first try "if (testCard.LstSummaries.All(x => x.AID == aId)) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Day), because it is converted to sql on runtime. Try to check without it.

Comment: Wow, that was it.. strange how the error had me looking at the wrong line..